# JSON post with authorization and getting request

Tags: java, android, json, post, https

So, hello everyone. I've got some problems with connection to server. I've worked with Yandex API and with VK.COM API and my methods were ok. But now I can't get any respone from server. I think, I don't do it right.

So the site is https://android-test.7g-demo.com
I also have API specification file. Here's what I have in it about POST-request.

```
# POST /oauth/token
```

- Request (application/json; charset=utf-8)

  - Headers

    ```
    Accept: application/json
    ```
  - Body

    ```
    {
        "username": "test@7glyphs.com",
        "password": "Test123",
        "grant_type": "password",
        "client_id": "2",
        "client_secret": "M1m2QgSdbRKWstTaVXlhdPotJ6WCC33rLLq3N6fK",
        "scope": "*"
    }
    ```
- Response 200 (application/json; charset=UTF-8)

  - Body

    ```
    {"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":31536000,"access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjkyYzAyYTE5ZGM2MjdmZDFhZTdkMzFiN2FkZTI1ODBlMWNmYTMxMjQxOWQzZmI3ZDNhYThmOGU0NmFjOWJlMGExOWI5YWI2NjI0ZmVjNmFmIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiOTJjMDJhMTlkYzYyN2ZkMWFlN2QzMWI3YWRlMjU4MGUxY2ZhMzEyNDE5ZDNmYjdkM2FhOGY4ZTQ2YWM5YmUwYTE5YjlhYjY2MjRmZWM2YWYiLCJpYXQiOjE1MDk0ODgyODgsIm5iZiI6MTUwOTQ4ODI4OCwiZXhwIjoxNTQxMDI0Mjg4LCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbIioiXX0.HrbgI2aYhqZCx_IwmvK7Y14HkOy2GzEL03o6Cwc7flqlb3Ijw2m-YFffEb5f9wX9Meo83iU3VSbdgx1oDpuJj5z3zOt0Q_QDJPn-seNG5Y0ob-BvAaMojUZFgbgLfL_xcatmW3TABKbC3NcUrgNym1Ru8qyBMvgT-ZY6iPlN13srWEH8qmMn0vYMB9-YJjfdz5mBHs-Y35APy4-6DdxiD_vKbppDBZCS1Nm_XULfoA-7MBVh9VOK2hngFxtERjiCZNol1FrljLO30gNwg2bD4WRZeFMH0o3ws3tkpDSwcbE2pQE8JokVXGZ46cJQConTmPhQ-yuPtCkggiwobs_QEMPLrTlkQSyIjLHm24xXlNQ3DLbw4AcDiOCDLYcrT8-Ef-9zYpDIxiYPnej4Fi4OHFanvxdwz-X8zqH8E8JKrdEPKPwMTE_Xx7xzazjyZKJY6y2GvVkU1BnvMa4VL5naRdYMp6TWnvo5hQiCBLpQXAbyH-U396aex2Nr5RctHdl2eM8KVhIHlofqMobUjeXwo-N4frpsAxjOj2uOco8zymFYmIirpjOCwyIkxiiF0lwzA6GOXzFlu2P6uzCpjvKTo2ID0pAT3wsA0Qf7lpDB0NjQlR3MAar6hHIncnDOYrndF8aX20i0fLDQvnpFZa43-z7GOXMO5f8ctTPO7q4Cuoc","refresh_token":"def50200d653d332230e5fbb8d094ba6fc99b6186739fdee26bd256171d07885ffe6afee1eb53247fe6a32c93dd31e53256d103b694007c5ec5ef8aadef0db64a7a4f46103182decb35bbfc2d39232b02649ebc1a32183a7cf1d498cf4aec14a4adde3ee8d708400811bdf4bf3ae4c067088ecd2ea1e8300e3c8a7a70e0900e62436a80c45069cb0552a067b230d74bce29e80233a71f47d0d9f670a26f7f660a1f81d52c2980a79b07e909df7871f1a9b39feb53a9f27e20599b5e66121c6866e91bf653fd78321ca6ad495e72ecb228386894375ec6ad5e200d8e9f1cc0df5d86b190214990ccbbe01bacc09114eebd70365f0d1f8a6932e2408deda013e160516d70b3aa209b7f5c9213ab58c3627dd700605a689ac8408d9e8f12bf3d21034441f22df1318d5a6cc011c776c92a41b6faec2497e3758f52c3bf288098db094a929ecfdf69a8dab6f693e97b7ba1afa1b5e25ab46e9b85314fc7ba78f6f5a60117d4e"}
    ```

But I don't know what to do with all of this. I write this code:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://android-test.7g-demo.com/?api.php");
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();

            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();

            jo.put("username", "test@7glyphs.com");
            jo.put("client_id", 2);
            jo.put("password", "Test123");

           BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            bos.write(jo.toString().getBytes());

            String result = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();
            Log.d("", "server response: " + result);

        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

But I have no answer from server. Maybe I should put token anywhere? Or maybe should use any library for oauth-request? Or my code shoud look another way? Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way and simplest way is to use retrofit instead of asyn task.
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Can you show me code example for my task? I tried some libraries and still couldn't do it. I don't want to try Retrofit, cause I think, that result would be the same.